# error: 'vector' in 'class Processus<double>' does not name a template type|

Tags: c++

I have an issue with my following code :

```
template<typename T>
class Processus {
public:
    typedef pair<double, T> state;
    typedef vector<state> result_type;

    Processus(int n = 0) : v(n+1) {}
    ~Processus() {};
    virtual result_type operator()() = 0;

    auto begin() const { return v.begin(); };
    auto end() const { return v.end(); };

    pair<T, T> minmax() const;

protected:
    vector<state> v;
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Processus<double>::vector<state>& P) {
    for (auto i = P.begin(); i != P.end(); ++i) os << i->first << ';' << i->second << endl;
    return os;
};
```

I have the following error :

> error: 'vector' in 'class Processus' does not name a template

for the line

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Processus<double>::vector<state>& P) {
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you offer a little bit more description about what you do or do not understand about what's going on here?  `vector` is not a template, do you understand why it's saying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like because `vector` is not defined in the class `Processus`.

Probably you mean this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Processus<double>::result_type& P) {
```

Comment: Thank you ! That is the answer !